# Using first Autocomplete to clear the value of the second Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following code.  It displays two Autocomplete controls.  The value selected in the first control determines the possible values of the second control. My problem is that when the "clear" button is clicked on the first control, it should also clear the second control since it is not longer valid.  The OnChange event in the first control captures the "clear" event and does change the underlying options list of the second control, however the actual value displayed is still there.  How can I programmatically clear it?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import NoSsr from '@material-ui/core/NoSsr';

export class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            aiList: [], 
            ucList: [], 
            aiLoading: true, 
            ucLoading: true
        };
        this.handleAIChange = this.handleAIChange.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/GetLeadAI')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (data) => { this.setState({ aiList: data, aiLoading: false })},
            (error) => { this.setState({ aiLoading: false, error })}
        )
    }

    handleAIChange = (event, values, reason) => {
        if (reason==='select-option') {
            fetch(`http://localhost:8080/GetUc?AIID=${encodeURIComponent(values.id)}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (data) => { this.setState({ ucList: data, ucLoading: false })},
                (error) => { this.setState({ ucLoading: false, error })}
            )
        }
        else {
            this.setState({ ucList: [], ucLoading: true })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <NoSsr>
                <div><br/></div>
                <Autocomplete
                    options={this.state.aiList}
                    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.description}
                    style={{ width: 600 }}
                    onChange={this.handleAIChange}
                    noOptionsText={this.state.aiLoading ? 'Loading AIs...' : 'No AI Data'}
                    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Lead AI" variant="outlined" />}
                />
                <div><br/></div>
                <Autocomplete
                    disabled={this.state.ucLoading}
                    options={this.state.ucList}
                    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.designCode + ' - ' + option.description}
                    style={{ width: 600 }}
                    noOptionsText={this.state.aiLoading ? 'Loading UCs...' : 'No UC Data'}
                    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Unpacked Chemical" variant="outlined" />}
                />
            </NoSsr>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to control the value of the Autocomplete, you need to control not only the `options`, but also the `value` that you have there.

Note that because you need to manage the value of the autocomplete - you also need to save and manage it once it's changed (internally - inside that autocomplete component).

```
this.state = { 
        aiList: [], 
        ucList: [], 
        aiLoading: true, 
        ucLoading: true,
        uiValue: null
    };

<Autocomplete
    options={...}
    onChange={(ev, value) => {
      this.setState({uiValue: value});
    }}
    value={this.state.uiValue}
    ....
/>
<button
    onClick={e => {
        this.setState({uiValue: null});
    }}
  >
    Reset
</button>
```

In your code - you need the `handleAIChange` function to also set the value of the second Autocomplete to null in order to reset it.